# Get the ssid of the currently connected wifi network by wpa_supplicant

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I'm using `wpa_supplicant` to connect to my wifi network. Since I'm using `dwm`, I want to show the SSID of the connected network in the panel. Is there a way to get the SSID of the connected network in `wpa_supplicant`?

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/chjj/dwm/blob/master/dwm-status#L241

Comment: @Bart: This seems to be using `nmcli` or `wicd-cli`, not `wpa_cli` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `iwgetid` from the `wireless_tools` package:

```
pacman -S wireless_tools
```

Then run

```
iwgetid -r
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current SSID with `wpa_cli` which is part of the `wpa_supplicant` package. No need to install `wireless_tools`...

`wpa_cli status` will spew out info of the current network. Just look for the `ssid` value in the output.

Comment: `Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory`. The accepted answer worked though.